# replace Guava's Bytes and Longs

Tags: java, arrays, guava

I'd like to implement the following function without using Guava's `Bytes` and `Longs`.

Do you know any solution in "plain" Java [8], without dependencies?

```
import com.google.common.primitives.Bytes;
import com.google.common.primitives.Longs;

public static byte[] toBytesFromString(String uuid) {
    UUID id = UUID.fromString(uuid);
    final Long msb = id.getMostSignificantBits();
    final Long lsb = id.getLeastSignificantBits();
    return Bytes.concat(Longs.toByteArray(msb), Longs.toByteArray(lsb));
}
```

Thanks,
Costin

Comment: You can copy the code from guava into your own method (assuming your project is Apache 2 compatible). Code is here for `Longs::toByteArray` for example: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/primitives/Longs.html#line.265

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public static byte[] toBytesFromString(String uuid) {
    UUID id = UUID.fromString(uuid);
    final Long msb = id.getMostSignificantBits();
    final Long lsb = id.getLeastSignificantBits();

    return ByteBuffer.allocate(2 * Long.BYTES).putLong(msb).putLong(lsb).array();

  }
```